# C#, parsing a date from string error

Tags: c#

In the C#, I am parsing a date from string, but it gives me error

```
DateTime.Parse("07/26/2012");
```

the error

```
 System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at System.DateTime.Parse(String s)
```

is it related to date format ? is it related to my pc setting ?

Thanks

Comment: try `DateTime.Parse("26/07/2012")`, you could say its a matter of culture.

Comment: I think it could be related to your current current Culture setting

Comment: Yes, I presume your system is set to a locale where dates are not in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` as that one is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, `Parse` uses your current culture. [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) allows you to manually specify the date format.

Try this instead:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("07/26/2012", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The `InvariantCulture` option allows you to ignore the current culture settings on the system.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the culture in which you are running this is not compatible with this date format. You could use `InvariantCulture`:

```
DateTime.Parse("07/26/2012", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Remember that the `Parse` method uses the current thread culture.

Answer (score 0):

Use ParseExact method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

```
string dateString = "Mon 16 Jun 8:30 AM 2008"; // Modified from MSDN
string format = "ddd dd MMM h:mm tt yyyy";

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format,
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: ParseExact is a method, not a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo( "en-US", false );
```

from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.71).aspx

To make sure the date is parsed correctly.